# How to stop Express server from exiting after error in synchronous code

Tags: node.js, express

**Environment**: Express 4.18.2, Node.js 20.10.0

**Question:** The default Express error handler crashes the server after an error.  Is this correct?  Am I misunderstanding the way Express handles errors?

**Background:** According to the docs Express automatically catches and handles all synchronous errors.

[Express Error Handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

> Errors that occur in synchronous code inside route handlers and
> middleware require no extra work. If synchronous code throws an error,
> then Express will catch and process it.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  throw new Error('BROKEN') // Express will catch this on its own.
})
```

However, on my simple test server the identical code causes the server to output the stack and then crash.

`Process exited with code 1`

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/', async (req, res, next)=> {
    throw new Error('BROKEN');
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('listening');
});
```

When the same error is put in a [try/catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block the server doesn't crash.

```
try {
    throw new Error('BROKEN');
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code that prevents Express from catching your `throw` is that you made your request handler `async`.  An async function will catch the `throw` and turn it into a rejected promise so the synchronous exception you are throwing never gets to Express.  And Express 4.x does not catch promise rejections so that rejection goes unhandled.

So, remove the `async` from your handler and the default Express error handler will catch the `throw` and keep your server from exiting/crashing on that error:

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res, next)=> {
    throw new Error('BROKEN');
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('listening');
});
```

---

The user experience of the default Express error handler is ugly (giving the user a server-side stack trace) so you probably don't want the default Express error handler anyway and should supply your own error handler as explained [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    throw new Error('BROKEN');
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log("got error");
    console.error(err.stack);

    // replace this with whatever UI you want to show the user
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});

app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('listening');
});
```

Comment: You are 100% correct about using a custom handler and sending an error page.  I removed that in my example to strip it down to its most basic level.